# "Ones" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: nouns

> Ones on epidemiology find relative risk ratios (RRs) very close to a value of 1, [...]

Does that refer to a group of people, or to some specific concept?

**Source**: https://examine.com/faq/is-saturated-fat-bad-for-me/ -> Heart Health -> 4th paragraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's poorly written.  "Ones" is a pronoun referring to the first line of the prior paragraph -- "Looking at reviews and meta-analysis' of controlled trials".

It is very poor writing to have a pronoun reach back that far.  (Plus, of course, "meta-analysis'" is wrong.)  Such a carelessly maintained web site is unlikely to be a reliable source of information.

Comment: +1 While I was laboring over my dissertation, you got to the heart of things in a tenth of the space.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Are you sure the "meta-analysis" term is wrong ? Apparently is a technical term in the research field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis

Comment: What's wrong (as described by StoneyB) is the apostrophe after the word, vs using the proper plural "meta-analyses".

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic example of why we ask for context.

> Ones on epidemiology find relative risk ratios (RRs) very close to a value of 1 . . .

Standing by itself the sentence is perplexing; but if we look at the immediately preceding paragraph the sense becomes parsable:

> Looking at reviews and meta-analysis' of controlled trials, there does not seem to be much evidence that saturated fat increases risk for Cardiovascular Diseases. However, replacing some saturated fat with polyunsaturated may reduce risk.
>
> Ones on epidemiology find relative risk ratios (RRs) very close to a value of 1, which is no effect; this suggests that there doesn't seem to be a strong relationship between saturated fat intake and risk for various conditions such as Cardiovascular Disease, Stroke, and Coronary Heart Disease.

It appears that *ones* is employed as a pronoun, with *reviews and meta-analysis'* as its referent.

This is difficult to discern, because the referent is separated from the pronoun by two longish sentences, and it's not the topic of either: it's buried in a subordinate clause.

That's bad writing. Indeed, all the writing on this page is execrable. Examine just the brief passage quoted here. The first sentence opens with a dangling modifier, employs *meta-analysis'* for the proper plural *meta-analyses*, and improperly capitalizes categories of disorder like *cardiovascular disease*. The second sentence interrupts the argument with a claim that replacing saturated fats reduces the same risk for whose very existence the first sentence claims that there is little evidence. And the conclusions of the first and third sentences are so similar that it's impossible to judge which of their differences are substantive and which mere 'elegant variation'—what exactly *is* the difference between "does not seem to be much evidence" and "doesn't seem to be a strong relationship"?

This sort of amateurish imitation of academic style should make you suspicious of the authors' qualifications: that they cannot write in this style suggests that they may be equally incapable of understanding what they read.